# is there a difference when putting a function call in a foreach loop vs the result in a variable?

Tags: php, foreach

Is there any difference in behaviour between

```
foreach(anyfunction($array) as $value){ //...do something
```

and

```
$values = anyfunction($array);
foreach($values as $value){//...do something
```

I am 99% sure that there is not a difference, however when looking into source codes of open source projects I mainly find the second variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's a scope thing.** The temporary variable generated by the `function_call()` use should *(not 100% how the garbage collector works in PHP but I'm 99% sure memory is freed when the loop ends)* be discarded once the `loop` ends. The `$values` will live longer.

It's all a question of whether you need it to outlive your loop. If you don't, `unset($values)` manually after the loop *(or when you no longer need it)* or just use it as a function call in the loop.

If `$values` takes a bit of memory and is not needed outside the loop, then go for the 1st variant. It's not a matter of readability as long as your function name is meaningful.

**PS**: *In `C++` we sometimes control variable scope with arbitrary `{...}` inside code as variables created after `{` are destroyed when the `}` hits.*

Answer (score 2):

Functionally, they are the same.  But the second is more readable.

Glancing at #1, the casual observer might see $array being the collection being iterated through instead of the result of anyfunction().

Personal preference.  I see myself doing both occasionally.  For me, more complex tasks are broken into smaller and smaller pieces, so they can be more easily followed and understood.

Practically, if you need to reuse $values later, the second is the obvious choice.